# How to select certain portion of image from octave

Tags: octave

Let say I have 410x218 size image. I want to read only the first 20x20 pixel of the image is it possible using octave packages especially the image pkg?

Comment: An image is just a Matrix with 3 dimesions, you can use normal indexing

Comment: Can you give some examples on how to do it in octave?

Comment: @EdcelCabreraVista They have a [whole page in the documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Index-Expressions.html) with examples. Did you find nothing there that was applicable?

Answer (score 0):

A RGB image is a m*n*3 matrix and you can use normal indexing to create a sub-image. Beaker added the [link to the documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Index-Expressions.html)

```
img = rand (218, 418, 3);
subimg = img (1:19, 1:19, :);
```